# What was Hermes' reason for siding with the Greeks in the Trojan War?

Tags: greek

It seems as if Hermes helped Zeus and other gods who sided with the Trojans in the war. What was his reason?

Comment: I could not find any clear quote in the Illiad for why he chose to side with the Greeks.  Why would he have chosen otherwise?

Comment: IIRC Hermes also guided Priam through the Achaean camp to recover Hector's body, so he might not have been completely one sided

Answer (score 1):

Hermes, along with some of the other gods, was more or less dragged into the war, with no actual interest for either side. He allowed his direct Trojan opponent, Leto (mother of Artemis and Apollo), to beat him in battle.
However, Hermes had a great interest in Odysseus, who was a descendant of his son Autolycus. But generally, he didn’t favor either side. Technically you could say he sided with the Greeks, but with no actual opinion on the war itself.
It could also be that Zeus is his father, but I wouldn’t count on that particularly.

Comment: I believe that Autolycus is not Hermes' son in the *Odyssey* (Pherecydes seems to be the source of that invention), though he did favor him. But where does Hermes show especial favor to Odysseus?

Comment: In _Odyssey_ 10, Hermes shows up out of the blue, after Odysseus has landed on Aiaia Island, to give the wandering hero instructions about how to avoid getting turned into an animal by Circe & also how to rescue those of his companions who have already suffered such an ignominy. Apollodorus, Athenaeus, Hyginus & Ovid also make references to the encounter.

Comment: @Adinkra I'm not sure I'd call that special favor, and both Athena and Ino-Leukothea help Odysseus on his journey. Also by that point Aeolus has helped him, too. Given that Poseidon was in favor of the Greeks but turned against Odysseus, I don't we can say for sure the Greeks would have attributed this action to any family ties.

Comment: I'd always been almost certain that the _Odyssey_ 10 preemptive rescue had something to do with Odysseus' descent from Hermes via Autolykos until you pointed out the absence of this genealogical connection in Homer. But ah, well, whatever the case, I'm guessing this must be what is being referring to by JavaJay - who I think has done well in parsing out a possible rationale for Hermes' motivations both on the Trojan battlefield & in Odysseus' adventures.

Comment: Also, your mention of Athena makes me think, though, that whatever the (otherwise unmentioned?) reason for it, the Aiaia meeting must be a special favour on the part of Hermes. Athena definitely goes out of her way to be Odysseus' patron in the _Odyssey_ , & apparently other divinities (viz. Leukothea, Aiolos & Hermes) like him enough to lend him their helping hand as well.

Comment: @Adinkra We should take this to chat to discuss it further, if you'd like, but a quick note: [Romero Recio](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/tesis?codigo=162356) and a few other scholars have advanced some interesting ideas along this line: essentially, because Poseidon was a god that hindered sailors, Greeks would pray to other sea divinities to help them on their journey. Ino, Aiolos (the wind god), Aphrodite, and Dionysus were all gods the Greeks actively prayed to in order that they may be safe. I mention it a little in my [earlier post](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/10453/398)

Comment: @Adinkra Btw, to ping me, type @ cmw (but no space). Otherwise I don't see when you have replied!